# Audio problem when concatenating MP4 videos

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to concatenate some mp4 videos but coundn't manage to solve the audio problems.

Here are [sample videos](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1q0dyDcDl6GqcTWROLF8ZrW1Ra1t4ou3J?usp=sharing), to be concatenated, in this order: 1, 2 and 3. A `concat.txt`is also supplied. `2.mp4` is a fragment of a larger video and was reencoded (not just cut).

None of my attempts worked. Most of them lead to gaps in the audio, some change the pitch of the voice. There's clearly a DTS issue I just don't know how to deal with.

Sometimes there are more than three videos to put together.

What I tried so far:

- The most obvious: `fmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i concat.txt -c copy out.mp4`. This complains a lot (non-monotonous DTS). Very poor result.
- Re-encoding video and audio: `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i concat.txt -c:v libx264 -c:a aac out.mp4`. Same poor result in a time consuming task. Using `copy` to avoid re-encoding just audio or just video leads nowhere.
- Running away from mp4: I converted all files to `avi` and to `ts` thinking that that could be an mp4 issue. Bad results with `avi` and slightly better results with `ts`. Nothing good, though.
- I tried playing with `-video_track_timescale`. No success.

I actually don't care about re-encoding the video, since the original has not a great quality already. But the audio issue must be solved.

I also hope for a generic solution, since I have many videos to handle and I wish to use just a script. Adjusting parameters for every single case would be a burden.

Using ffmpeg version 4.3.3 and Debian 11.

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.3.3-0+deb11u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
```

**Edit**

Here are the `ffprobe` results for each input file:

```
$ for i in [123].mp4; do echo; echo "------------ $i"; ffprobe $i; done

------------ 1.mp4
ffprobe version 4.3.3-0+deb11u1 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.00, start: 0.040000, bitrate: 8842 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 8669 kb/s, 25.11 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 167 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler

------------ 2.mp4
ffprobe version 4.3.3-0+deb11u1 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:07:24.45, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 219 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 81 kb/s, 25 fps, 30 tbr, 115200 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/11/2020.
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/11/2020.

------------ 3.mp4
ffprobe version 4.3.3-0+deb11u1 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:18.58, start: 0.040000, bitrate: 314 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 213 kb/s, 25.05 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: `concat` demuxer is a finicky one as all its files must have the same codec configurations. Please add `ffprobe` outputs of these 3 mp4 files to your post

Comment: @kesh I think they all have the same encodings, but perhaps someone can see some difference I can't. The `ffprobe`s were added to the question.

Comment: The middle one is 44.1k while the others are 48k. So the pitches in the middle audio gets higher as it is forced to 48k and also duration is compressed as more samples get pushed out per second. So, long story short, can't use `-f concat` on these 3 files. You need to pre-resample middle track or use `concat=n=3:v=2:a=2` filter with 3 inputs.

Comment: I think this should be trivial, but with `ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v copy v2.mp4` the new video plays ok in vlc, but the concatenation leads to a video length with more than 1 hour when it should be less than 10 minutes. I guess that could have something to do with video/audio sync...

Comment: Yikes. Which of video/audio is bloated to 1 hour?

Comment: Another approach (if you are only expecting mixed audio sampling rates) is to use the `concat` demuxer for video only and put it in an MKV container and pipe it to the second ffmpeg call, where the piped-in video stream is combined with `-filter_complex [1:a][2:a][3:]concat=n=3:a=1:v=0[aout]` (you may need to add `-aresample` filter to match sampling rates). If this makes sense to you...

Comment: The second (2.mp4). There's something wrong there with DTS. I separated video and audio streams. Audio streams concatenate ok; video concatenation transforms the middle video from 7:24 to 1 hour. I know nothing about what DTS is for...

Comment: Got it!  I had to re-encode both audio and video. Audio was resampled to 48K to match the other files. My problem was that I did't realize that the default `libx264` was changing the frame rate to 30fps. After a break and a cup of coffee, this solved: `ffmpeg -fflags igndts -i 2.mp4 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v libx264 -filter:v fps=25 2_converted.mp4`. 
Thanks @kesh for hints and insight!